# Is there a standard clojure macro for first-not-nil?

Tags: macros, clojure

I'm am looking for a macro that does effectively the opposite of this `maybe-m`. That is, I want the result of the first expression that returns non-nil *without evaluating the remaining expressions*. This last part is important because if the "solution" uses lazy-sequences then they will be evaluated in chunks...meaning the expressions could be evaluated when I don't want them to.

Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

```
(defn really-cool-stuff [a b c]
  (first-not-nil
    (operation1 a b) ; <-- this returns nil,
    (operation2 b c) ; <-- this returns non-nil, the result is returned
    (operation3 a b c))) ; <-- this is not evaluated
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `nil` is falsey, [`or`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/or) will do what you are looking for.

```
(defn really-cool-stuff [a b c]
  (or
    (operation1 a b)
    (operation2 b c)
    (operation3 a b c)))
```

The only exception is if the functions could potentially return `false`. In that case, you can build a macro that mimics `or`, except with a more strict conditional.

```
(defmacro or-nil?
  ([] nil)
  ([x] x)
  ([x & next] `(let [or# ~x] (if (nil? or#) (or-nil? ~@next) or#))))
```

Comment: gorgeous! luckily, in this case the operations will always return truthy values when not returning nil.